# trace() is not working in flashbuilder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

i'm trying to use actionscript 3.0 and using trace(), it never outputs content of trace of variable either in flash player or in output area?
how to coorect or should i enable something? 
whats the problem?

Comment: how do i install debug version of flash player? i'm running on windows xp.........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, trace only works when in debug.
If you want information to get dumped out when running "release", you'll need to use the [logging api](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_09.html) that flex provides.

Answer (score 3):

When you test your movie, are you using "Run Application" or "Debug Application"? I'm not sure if this has changed in 4, but if you just run it, trace actions are omitted by default.

Comment: yes i used run application,should i use debug application? what about flash player? some tell to use debug version? i don't understand?

Comment: Yes, you should have the debug version of the flash player installed and use "debug application". It then displays traces in the output window of FB.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also view the output from the debug version of the flash player from the command line.  Then you don't have to run the application in the Flash Builder debuger.  You need to create a mm.cfg file They have changed where this file has to be located a number of times so there is a lot of misinformation about where the file goes.  The instructions here look like the most upto date - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html